# Can not update the list of items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, use-effect, material-table

My list of items is not being updated when I do a delete of a row even though the console.log(data) results in one less item after deleting the row, but the console.log('list of items after: ', listOfitems) gives me all full items even those that are deleted.

```
const [listOfitems, setListOfitems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    getListOfitems();
}, [])
```

Please let me know what could be possibly wrong here:

```
                            editable={{

                                onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
                                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                            {
                                                console.log('list of items before: ', listOfitems)
                                                console.log('oldData.item_key;: ', oldData.item_key)
                                                const indexToDelete = oldData.item_key;
                                                console.log(indexToDelete)
                                                const data =
                                                    listOfitems.filter(
                                                        (item) => ((item.item_key !== oldData.item_key))
                                                    )
                                                setListOfitems(data);

                                                console.log(data)
                                                console.log(setListOfitems(data))
                                                deleteitem(oldData);
                                                setListOfitems(data);
                                                console.log('list of items after: ', listOfitems)
                                            }
                                            resolve();
                                        }, 1000);
                                    }),
                            }}
```

Comment: if you only want to track the change on state, use the hooks like that: useEffect(() => console.log(the_state_you_need))

Comment: No for some reason my setListofitems is not firing

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the useEffect hook is an array of values that the hook depends on.  In your example you passed an empty array, which is great for making the hook work like `ComponentDidMount()`.  However, since your hook now depends on *no* values, it will never fire again.  In the below example, passing `listOfItems` into that array will cause the hook to fire whenever that piece of state changes.  Not seeing the rest of your code, but based on your description of the problem, this is my best guess as to a solution for you.

Hope this helps.

```
const [listOfitems, setListOfitems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    getListOfitems().then((listOfitems) => {
        setListOfitems(listOfitems);
    });
    getDocuments();
}, [listOfItems]);
```

Comment: However, this may lead to some issues with looping, since you're also calling `setListOfItems()` in the hook.  You may need to do some refactoring, but the key to getting your data to rerender the way you're describing is in using that second argument properly.

Comment: No it is not passing empty array as the getListofitems is a function that connects to a server and from there loads this list.

Comment: async function getListOfitems() {
  const res = await fetch("http://" + host + ":5000/itemlist");
  console.log('getListOfitems')
  const value = await res.json();

  setListOfitems(value);

 }

Comment: I have tried to change my useEffect to  useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect')
  getListOfitems();
  
 }, [])

Answer (score 0):

The `set*` methods for state are asynchronous, so if you try to access `listOfitems` immediately after calling `setListOfitems`, you could be using the old value and not the newly updated one.

You could use a separate `useEffect` method that is dependent on the value being set in the first one (use the second param like `[listOfitems]`). This other method should get triggered *after* the update.

In short - the data IS being updated, but your console.log is displaying the old value before the update is complete.

edit: Code example:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    getListOfitems()
    // console.log here may NOT show the new listOfitems value because
    // setListOfitems is asynchronous, and getListOfitems may also be
}, []) // only loads on the initial mount
```

I assume `getListOfitems` will retrieve the data from an external source initially, and calls `setListOfitems` inside it. The code in the post does not show what is happening.

A second `useEffect` could look like:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    // do something with listOfitems
}, [listOfitems]) // gets called every time listOfitems is updated
```

Comment: Could you please write the second useEffect code? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @SS Since your code example does not show what `getListOfitems` is doing - it's difficult to know when it should be called. Is this pulling the latest list (e.g. does it just
```return listOfitems``` ? Or does it actually call another function to retrieve it from an external source?)

Answer (score 0):

Every time the component is rendered a new const state is assigned to useState hook. In you case every time your component is rerendred this line runs assigning a new value to the listOfitems.

```
const [listOfitems, setListOfitems] = useState([]);
```

This means that console logging out the state before the component rerenders would return the old state.

Console.log(data) results in the correct state because you simply filter and return a new array.

As **dvfleet413** mentioned you do not include the listOfItems in the argument array of the useEffect meaning that your component only renders once.